# Import "___" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation, pylance

Whenever I install a new library, I get this error from VScode. I searched up how to fix it and got confused.

One solution told me to Ctrl+Shift+P, select the python interpreter. on my computer, and select ok, but that did not work. Other solutions speak of accessing settings.json, but I could not understand what that is and how to access it.

Is there a simple fix for this issue? It happens for all libraries not just some specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which interpreter you are using, in vscode it is displayed in the lower right corner.

[image]

Then, you need to install the third-party package in the interpreter environment you are using.

You will have a better experience using a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: So third-party package meaning the library I am trying to use, right? So does that mean I should use pip install using the terminal inside VSCode? When I run it again, it tells me that Requirement already satisfied.

Comment: Yes, so you need to use the correct interpreter.